# Magento2 get tax rate on product view page

Tags: magento2, tax

I want to get tax rate (percentage) on product-view page. Following code only shows text of tax:

```
$currentProduct->getAttributeText('tax_class_id')
```

Thanks for help!
martn

Answer (score 10):

I achieved getting tax rates by using *\Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface*:

```
$rate = $this->taxCalculation
              ->getCalculatedRate($productTaxClassId, $customerId, $storeId);
```

Comment: hi @Lukas,can we get the tax amout from product id in magento2?

Comment: where need to keep this piece of code can you please give complete instruction.

Comment: @jafarpinjar Tax Amount depends on given Tax Rules. Tax rules depends on products tax class, country, customer group and so on. So if you have a product id try to find the products tax class id and use my code to get the customers tax amount.

Comment: @irshad use dependency injection (DI) to inject \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculation

Comment: @Lukas:  How can we display separate tax on selecting particular stores from the 
                dropdown? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304011/magento-2-3-x-how-can-we-display-separate-tax-the-on-selecting-particular-store

Answer (score 0):

You can get tax rate by:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$taxCalculation = $objectManager->create( 'Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate' )->load( <tax_rate_id> , 'tax_calculation_rate_id' );

$rate = $taxCalculation->getRate();
```

where `<tax_rate_id>` get from **Tax Zones and Rates** admin screen /tax/rate/ , or you can get it programmatically with TaxRuleModel

Comment: Load is deprecated, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can get rate object by instantiating 'Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate' class and calling loadByCode() method on the instance. The tax_code needs to be passed as a parameter of the method.